# Problema de Conexión con SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server

Tengo un problema con la conexión a la BD de `SQL` desde `java`. 
El mismo proyecto lo tengo con `MySQL` y funciona correcto.

**Error que me sale**:

> Exception [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.1.v20100817-r8050): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Exception Description: Configuration error.  Class [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver] not found.

**Las conexiones**:

```
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://CNTSRV17:1433/BDConectaDesa;"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="Usr_Cob2"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.type" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="concob2$2014"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
    </properties>
```

Comment: está el jar de JTDS en el classpath?

Comment: agregaste el Jar de conexión JDBC del JTDS al PATH de tu proyecto?.

Comment: gracas hermano, eres lo máximo.

Comment: he instalado el jar de JTDS pero me sale otro error.

Comment: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.1.v20100817-r8050): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection timed out: connect
Error Code: 0

Comment: este es el erro que me sale cuando ejecuto mi proyecto.